# authenticate google apps script to use google cloud run instance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-run

I've got a Google Apps Script attached to a Google Sheet that is triggered when a new entry comes in. I've also got a Google Cloud Run instance for a Flask app that I access through an end-point.

Currently it allows unauthenticated invocations but I want to only allow authenticated invocations. How do I go about doing this? I can't access the metadata server as its outside of GCP and the [Calling From Outside GCP](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#calling-from-outside-gcp) suggests following the [Identity-Aware Proxy sample code](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) however IAP does not work for Cloud Run...

Is there any simple way of doing this?